# Explicit method naming or generic method name with call purpose parameter

Tags: java, methods, fully-qualified-naming

I sometimes stumble upon a decision for method naming on public API methods.

Variant A:

```
public void play();
public void stop();
public void pause();
```

Variant B:

```
public enum CallType {
            PLAY,
            STOP,
            PAUSE
        }
public void execute(CallType type);
```

I think for the API client it is more convenient to have interface of variant A, since no parameter(and checking!) is needed.

But I also think with variant B the public interface is also smaller and the task for the developer is easier.

What is your opinion about these approaches?

Comment: Please avoid asking primarily opinion-based questions. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: An argument for (or against) B is that if `CallType`'s set of values were to change, then instead of compile-time failures of an implementing class, runtime issues may come up instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of call types is *reasonably* low, I'd say it is worth having separate methods for each action (variant A). It makes the interface easier to read and you don't have to divert the user of your class to an additional JavaDoc page (of the enum) in order to be informed on which are his options of using your interface. As the number of call types grows, you might get an interface with larger contract (that is, a higher number of methods), so it might be worth using the enum. But be aware that in this case your `execute` method might grow too large (probably with a `switch` statement with a lot of cases).

I think the answer should be given by what `reasonably` means, and there's no exact answer to this. It depends on developer preferences, coding standards in your organization, static code check rules (if you have an analyzer) and so on and so forth.